# Removing arm64-v8a from package have no effect

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I am about to publish my Xamarin.Android app, but are having some issues with Samsung S7 and one suggestion is to remove arm64-v8a support.

I unchecked arm64-v8a from Supported ABIs under Android Build in Xamarin Studio before creating a package. But when I extracted the apk, I see that arm64-v8a is still there, and uploading to play store I see that arm64-v8a is supported.

Comment: ARMv8-A allows ARMv7-A (32-bit) applications to be executed and thus your app would be compatible with either cpu that the S7 comes with. As far as the `arm64-v8a` libs still being there, verify that you are changing the "Release" Build-based Supported ABIs option and not the debug one

Comment: I checked that I changed for for Release, so that was not the case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up generating apks for each architecture following the instructions from James Montemagno in this post: http://motzcod.es/post/112072508362/how-to-keep-your-android-app-size-down

I left arm64-v8a out and generated apks for only armeabi and armeabi-v7.